# Unresolved Link Error

Tags: c++, function, mfc, dialog, lnk2019

I'm receiving this error when I try and compile.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Serial::WritePort(char * const)" (?WritePort@Serial@@QAEXQAD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CThermotronDlg::OnBnClickedButton2(void)" (?OnBnClickedButton2@CThermotronDlg@@QAEXXZ)
```

I have included all the required header files but when I attempt to call the my WritePort function(located in my sConfig.cpp) in my main dialog.cpp I get this link error. Also every .cpp file is in the same folder so I'm not trying to reference files in different locations  below is the for the WritePort Function and the block where it is being called.

WritePort

```
void WritePort(char buffer[])
{

HANDLE sSerial = CreateFile(L"COM3",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
OpenPort();
DWORD bytes;
WriteFile(sSerial, buffer,sizeof(buffer),&bytes,NULL);
}
```

Block

```
void CThermotronDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
```

{

```
CString str; str.Format(L"%d",Index);
LPTSTR Dwell = new TCHAR[1000];
USES_CONVERSION;
char* buffer =T2A(Dwell);
MyListEx.GetItemText(Index,1,Dwell,1000);

Serial Port;
Port.WritePort(buffer);


AfxMessageBox(Dwell,MB_OK,NULL);
```

}

Comment: Something tells me seeing the implementation of `Serial` or more importantly, the lack in code of any `Serial::WritePort` implementation (note class qualifier) would lead you to your problem, and its eventual resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
void WritePort(char buffer[])
```

be

```
void Serial::WritePort(char buffer[])
```

?

Comment: Thank You I'm such an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

Function `WritePort` needs to be part of `Serial` class, as you are using it as `Port.WritePort(buffer)` and not `WritePort(buffer)`

```
void Serial::WritePort(char buffer[])
{
bool umm;
HANDLE sSerial = CreateFile(L"COM3",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
OpenPort();
DWORD bytes;
umm = WriteFile(sSerial, buffer,sizeof(buffer),&bytes,NULL);
}
```